# Deny from host (mod_authz_host) is ineffective

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, web-server

I'm attempting to configure an Apache HTTP Server installation and I'm having a problem getting the Deny directive to work properly in both a general or VirtualHost context for some reason.

I stripped out as much as I could to try to isolate the problem, yet even this simple case doesn't work.

The httpd.conf file is simply:

```
ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

The virtual host's configuration file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site-1.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site-1.mydomain.com/docroot/

    <Directory />
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Yet for some reason, the Deny directive doesn't work, and site-1.mydomain.com/index.html for example, loads normally when requested.

What could I be missing here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you changing the right config file? Are you restarting the server after doing these changes?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I'm using the correct configuration file, because if I change the directive to Location, access is denied as expected. I just need to get it working for Directory as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    <Location />
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    </Location>
```

Comment: +1, With `Directory /` one would refer to the root of the filesystem, not the DocumentRoot.

Comment: Using `<Location />` works correctly, however I am concerned about using it to restrict directories deeper within the webspace, because of the warning presented in the apache documentation [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html], which instructs never to use location for this purpose. 


How can I make it work using `<Directory />` ? I tried using `<Directory /var/www/site-1.mydomain.com/docroot/>` but that didn't work. Any advice would be appreciated.